# How to close a batch file before a command is completed

Tags: windows

I need a batch file to run hidden, or at least minimized. Another alternative is to run the batch file, and, have it closed while an operation continues. This is the code :

```
@echo off
cls
echo "Updating Application to latest verion, takes a couple of seconds..."
if exist %USERPROFILE%\Documents (copy "\\servername\folder\WA.accdb" %USERPROFILE\Documents /y)
cd \
cd %USERPROFILE%\Documents
WA.accdb
exit
```

The 2nd to last line, opens the Access Database. Batch file's command prompt Windows only closes after user closes the Access database. Would like to either minimize the command prompt Window, or, exit the batch file while Access database is still running.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `Start` command.

Change the `WA.accdb` line to `start WA.accdb`

More info available from `start /?`:

> Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command.

Maybe use Start's `/B` switch if needed:

> B - Start application without creating a new window.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. Replace:

`WA.accdb`

`exit`

with

`start WA.accdb`

`exit`

Comment: What's the semicolon after exit supposed to do?

Comment: @techie007 | Nothing. The result will be the same I just use it from SQL habits. The main point was the above line. I can take it out if it bothers anyone.

Comment: Doesn't bother me. I figured it was a typo/habit from 'real' programming, but just in case it was something new in Batch I didn't know about I figured it was worth asking. :)

Comment: Actually, [it's something _old_ that you didn't know about](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/Softwares/cmd/guide/differences.html).  It's something old, idiosyncratic, largely undocumented, and not to be relied upon.

Comment: @JdeBP Just FYI, that link is malformed, but doesn't seem to work even if properly formed.  Do you have an updated link?